# To what extent can a company sponsor the military?

Tags: united-states, advertisements, military

In the show "Space Force", the underfunded branch of the military makes a sponsorship deal with a company in order to raise some funds, where the general participates in a commercial and says something nice about the product.

I have not seen anything like this in real life, beyond "company X supports the US military", but I don't have the impression of a *quid pro quo* in those cases.

What laws govern the legality of such an advertising agreement, if any?

Comment: I like it.  The Abrams Tank by Verizon.